# Compiling geos without root CentOS

Tags: php, compilation, centos, geos

I have been trying to compile geos on my restrcited(no root) environment and I am having some difficulties...

I did the following

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
tar jxf geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.4.2
nano ~/.bash_profile
# I added PATH=$PATH:$HOME/local/bin export PATH
./configure --enable-php --prefix=$HOME/local/ && make clean && make
```

And Im getting the following errors

```
Making all in php
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/myname/test/geos-3.4.2/php'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/myname/test/geos-3.4.2/php'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include/geos   `/usr/local/bin/php-config --includes` -DCOMPILE_DL_GEOS -I../capi -I../include -I./opt/alt/php53/usr/include/ -pedantic -Wall -ansi -Wno-long-long  -ffloat-store -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -MT geos_la-geos.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/geos_la-geos.Tpo -c -o geos_la-geos.lo `test -f 'geos.c' || echo './'`geos.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include/geos -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DCOMPILE_DL_GEOS -I../capi -I../include -I./opt/alt/php53/usr/include/ -pedantic -Wall -ansi -Wno-long-long -ffloat-store -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -MT geos_la-geos.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/geos_la-geos.Tpo -c geos.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/geos_la-geos.o
geos.c:26:17: error: php.h: No such file or directory
geos.c:27:54: error: ext/standard/info.h: No such file or directory
geos.c:28:72: error: Zend/zend_exceptions.h: No such file or directory
```

According to some github, this happens with MAMP too

> This happens because GEOS requires PHP header files from the original PHP source, and MAMP does not include those.

EDIT 1:

I have also added this in ~/local/share/config.site

```
CPPFLAGS=-I./opt/alt/php53/usr/include/
LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/local/lib
```

php.h is located here: `./opt/alt/php53/usr/include/php/main/php.h`

info.h: `./opt/alt/php53/usr/include/php/ext/standard/info.h`

zend_exceptions.h: `./opt/alt/php53/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_exceptions.h`

EDIT 2:

Last thing: my ./configure tells me this

```
checking for php-config... /usr/local/bin/php-config
checking for php... /usr/local/bin/php
```

So my question, if Im on the right track for solving this, is how do I include my php header files while compiling geos in a non root evnironment in centOs ?

Im quite lost to be honest !

Comment: `PATH='$HOME/local/bin:$PATH'` with single quotes is an error and will break things. Luckily, `~/.bash_rc` is not the correct file for that so you didn't see that breakage (but if you `echo "$PATH"` you'll also see that your addition didn't work, unless it happened to be there already). You need double quotes on the assignment for the variables to expand.

Comment: it was an error in my explanation, I in fact added this in .bash_profile `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/local/bin
export PATH`

Comment: On one line that's an error also but for a different reason. On one line that assignment only applies to the `export` call... but actually that happens to work coincidentally enough but it still isn't correct. That should be on two lines. Anyway, that's not related to your problem in any way.

Comment: We can't give you a generally applicable answer here, as the details will depend heavily on the web host you are using and the way they've configured their systems. Have you asked them for assistance?

Comment: Ya, and their only answer is you need root access to compile and install php extensions not provided. Please consider upgrading to a dedicated server or VPS.  (which means 15 to 80$ month) Its godaddy btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the path to your PHP installation does **not** start with a `.` - not from inside the `geos-3.4.2` folder anyway, and certainly not from inside an arbitrary source folder.
You should make that path absolute.

<s>I'm assuming the `opt` folder is in your user folder, so the full  path would be `$HOME/opt/alt/php53/usr/`.</s> Thanks for the clarification, the full path should then be `/opt/alt/php53/usr/`.
You need to add the `bin` folder to your `PATH` variable, the `include` folder to `CPPFLAGS` and the `lib` folder to `LDFLAGS`.
With `$HOME/local/` this is not necessary, since that is the `PREFIX`, and will be added automatically.
Also note that when adding stuff to your `PATH` variable, you should add it to the **beginning** instead of the end, so that it will take precedence over system binaries.

I also suggest you undo the changes you made to `~/local/share/config.site` (or remove the file, if it didn't exist), as options there will affect **all** automake-based projects.
You should rather pass `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` as arguments to `configure`.

After all that, your command block should look something like:

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
tar jxf geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.4.2
export PATH="/opt/alt/php53/usr/bin:$PATH"
./configure --enable-php --prefix="$HOME/local" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/alt/php53/usr/include" LDFLAGS="/opt/alt/php53/usr/lib" && make clean && make
```

Comment: Currently, trying and compiling your solution. The `.` was found using the `find` command. And the php installation is in the root folder meaning `/opt/alt/php53/user/bin`. Modified your solution in consequence. Still waiting for the end of  the compilation. Thanks for the heads up though. And Yes I created the config.site based on my google research lol. I'm not used compiling stuff

Comment: Alright, updated my answer. Just fyi, paths beginning with `./` are relative to the current directory, so you have to recalculate them when using them in another directory - or just make them absolute, as most build system (I've encountered) can't handle relative paths anyway.